# Как реализовать обновление данных php(таблицы MySQL) через ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Ребята, кто может подсказать, как можно через ajax редактировать статью(она в таблице БД), которая до этого выводилась через PDO? Как редактировать данные если они в таблице html я нашел, а вот если они выводятся в виде Object PDO, нет. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Вот код вывода:

```html
<?php 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id";
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $query=$pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(['id'=>$id]);

  $article=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  $website_title=$article->title;
?>

<div class="jumbotron">
          <h2><?=$article->title?></h2>
          <p><b>Автор статьи:</b> <mark><?=$article->avtor?></mark></p>
          <? 
            $date = date('d ',$article->date);
            $array = ["Января","Февраля","Марта","Апреля","Мая","Июня","Июля","Августа","Сентября","Октября","Ноября","Декабря"];
            $date .= $array[date('n',$article->date)-1];
            $date .= date(' H:i',$article->date);
          ?>
          <p><b>Время публикации </b> <u><?=$date?></u></p>
          <p>
            <?=$article->intro?>
            <br><br>
            <?=$article->text?>
          </p>
        </div>
```

[image: статья]
[image: окно редактирования]

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь файл, в котором выводишь данные для редактирования сразу в

- Добавить новость `/news/add.php`
- Редактировать новость `/news/edit.php?id=123`
- Смотреть новость `/news/view.php?id=123`

Но редактировать можно также и на странице добавления новой записи, если предварительно передавать id новости. `/news/add.php?id=123`

А в скрипте уже проверяешь наличие параметра, проверяешь наличие новости по указанному айдишнику, если новость есть, подставляешь ее данные в форму и редактируешь. После отправки данных на сервер, также проверяешь наличие айдишника. Если его нет, то новая запись, если есть, тогда изменение записи.

А как данные отправлять (обычно или с помощью ajax) по сути все равно.